# Passing parameter to load data from DB after login with Django Auth App

Tags: django, authentication

I am new user of Django.

I want to use the built in Django Auth app for secure login. However, once a user logs in, based upon the username, I want to load it's data on the first page (lets call it welcome or home page). If I write my own login, I get stuck with URLs. All my pages become http://127.0.0.0.1:8000/login/..... I don't know where this /login/ comes from (it's written in settings file but who calls it I don't know) so after losing hope, I went for Auth login again.

I am sure there is a nice and easy way to retrieve the username but where should I write this code? in the login view of Auth app? would then that code will become part of my application?

Answer (score 0):

Information about the user that's currently logged in is stored in the `request.user` object (`request` being the first parameter of every view function). `request.user` is an instance of the `User` class from `django.contrib.auth`. So, you can pass the user object to your templates and make all the information about the logged in user avalable that way (`user.username`, `user.email`, etc).